# array to tree in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the array in the following format

```
[{"pk_location_id":1,"locationname":"Oman","parent_location_id":0,"has_children":true},
 {"pk_location_id":2,"locationname":"Muscat","parent_location_id":1,"has_children":true},
{"pk_location_id":3,"locationname":"Seeb","parent_location_id":1,"has_children":false},
{"pk_location_id":4,"locationname":"Ruwi","parent_location_id":2,"has_children":false}]
```

The above array i want to convert it into tree, referred the following documentation 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-to-tree

The following is the stack trace i am getting ERROR:-

> > ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
> >         at SafeSubscriber._next (dropdown-treeview-select-demo.component.ts:91)
> >         at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:239)
> >         at SafeSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:186)
> >         at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:127)
> >         at Subscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
> >         at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:127)
> >         at CatchSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)
> >         at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
> >         at MapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:91)

Kindly anyone help me out in this

Thanks
Amruta Wandakar

Answer (score 0):

I think that your array should use `id` and `pid` instead of `pk_location_id` and `parent_location_id`

The following works when running it on the page you linked to. See (https://runkit.com/embed/4yb7bzbtbqof):

```
array2tree(
[{"id":1,"locationname":"Oman","pid":0,"has_children":true}, 
 {"id":2,"locationname":"Muscat","pid":1,"has_children":true}, 
 {"id":3,"locationname":"Seeb","pid":1,"has_children":false}, 
 {"id":4,"locationname":"Ruwi","pid":2,"has_children":false}
])
```

Comment: this works fine like this in the link but i am using this in angular 2 so there i am facing the error(in my post already given stack trace), Kindly help me out in this. thanks

Comment: I can't help much without seeing the angular code. It looks like you used the `dropdown-treeview-select-demo.component.ts`  from /ngx-treeview as a start and is modifying that. The error seems to be on line 91 of your  component. It looks like there is an error in the `.subscribe` handler of an observable there.

Comment: Yes i am using ngx-treeview, this need data in parent and child format but i will get flat array, so i had used the arraytotree method but thats not working. Is there any way to convert array to tree to provide ngx-treeview.